# showing counter in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql query given below. I which counter has been used. if i enter category Id 1 for 3 times then counter is coming 3 which is correct but with this i want if i do not enter then different coloumn should come with NO.
output should be

```
      KU      Electrical  
Yes   6       2  
No    1       2
```

In this KU and Electrical are my sale channel name. Yes means counter of enteries of KU  and No means which have not entered. Please help out in this. i am struggling

```
select 
  SalesChannel.name, 
  Transaction.category_id, 
  count(Transaction.category_id) as "count"
from outlets Outlet 
inner join transactions Transaction on Outlet.id = Transaction.outlet_id 
inner join sale_channels SalesChannel on SalesChannel.id = Outlet.sale_channel_id
group by Transaction.category_id;
```

below are three tables which I used

1) transactions

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `outlet_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_units` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mop` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `transactions`
--

INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `zone_id`, `state_id`, `city_id`, `category_id`, `sub_category_id`, `brand_id`, `model_id`, `outlet_id`, `no_of_units`, `mop`) VALUES
(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, '6.00'),
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, '6.00'),
(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, '2.00'),
(4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, '2.00');
```

2) outlets

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `outlets` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `outlet_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_channel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `outlets`
--

INSERT INTO `outlets` (`id`, `outlet_code`, `name`, `zone_id`, `state_id`, `city_id`, `sale_channel_id`, `is_active`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, '1508', 'Ashok electricals', 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, '2016-10-03 00:00:00', '2016-10-03 00:00:00'),
(2, '1233', 'vinayak electricals', 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, '2016-10-04 00:00:00', '2016-10-04 00:00:00');
```

3) sale_chennals

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sale_channels` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sale_channels`
--

INSERT INTO `sale_channels` (`id`, `name`, `is_active`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 'KU', 1, '2016-10-03 00:00:00', '2016-10-03 00:00:00'),
(2, 'Electricals', 1, '2016-10-04 00:00:00', '2016-10-04 00:00:00');
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f497/1

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by category. That means you get one result row per category. In each of these rows you show the count and a sale channel name. This sale channel name is just one of the names found in the records for the category arbitrarily chosen.

I suppose you want to count per category and sale channel. Hence your group by clause should be `group by SalesChannel.name, Transaction.category_id`:

```
select 
  SalesChannel.name, 
  Transaction.category_id, 
  count(Transaction.category_id) as "count"
from outlets Outlet 
inner join transactions Transaction on Outlet.id = Transaction.outlet_id 
inner join sale_channels SalesChannel on SalesChannel.id = Outlet.sale_channel_id
group by SalesChannel.name, Transaction.category_id;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f497/2

This result, however, doesn't show an entry for Electricals / category 2, because there is no transaction for this combination in the table. If you want to show a zero count for this, you'd have to create the complete result set (i.e. all combinations of channel and category, whether they have a transaction or not) first. Then you'd outer join the transactions:

```
select 
  sc.name, 
  c.id as category_id, 
  count(t.id) as "count"
from sale_channels sc
cross join categories c
left join outlets o on o.sale_channel_id = sc.id
left join transactions t on t.outlet_id = o.id and t.category_id = c.id
group by sc.name, c.id;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60e998/5

Comment: y you added here cross and left join instead of inner join? cant we get required result with inner join?\

Comment: No. A SQL query can only show what is there. When there is no record for the combination Electricals / category 2, we must create it in order to show it. This is what the cross join does. Have you tried the queries? Do you see the difference in the results? Are you satisfied with the results?

Comment: its giving me sales channel name multiple times. there should be KU 6 times if its category id added for 6 times. multiple counters shouold be there.

Comment: The query is giving you a count per channel name and category. Do you *want* a count per per channel name and category? Or a count per per channel name only? Or what else?

Comment: count per per channel name and category

Comment: So the query gets you what you want. You may want to have the data presented differently (channel name in columns and category in rows or vice versa), but SQL is not made for this. SQL gets you the data and you write a program (in a programming language) or use a report tool to care about the layout.

Comment: can you please make it access in such way so that both conditions would work, yes or no. . then half of my problem will be solved. you tried already alot. please make it in right way please.

Comment: Are you talking of three dimensions; the channel, the category, the yes/no? Are you going to write a program that will display the values in a 3D cube? Think about how your results shall *really* look like. You need a before-known number of columns (e.g. two columns for yes and no, one column for the channel name, one column for the category). With all the information already got, you should finally be able to write this query. If not, then it's just not time for you to write such query yet, and you should read and practice before doing it.

Comment: let me explain more. see , I have three main coulmns sales_channel that are KU and electricals etc then category Id which are associated with sale_channel_id. then yes no. Now Yes no will be the counter for example if unit_of_sale and mop are < 0 then counter of category id will come under the No . if its greater then counter of category id will come under Yes. I hope you have cleared now.